# How to prevent modal popup from closing on button click

Tags: asp.net, modalpopup

I have to open a modal popup on link click .In that popup i have to take some user details and on submit some server side code has to be executed and new popup is to be opened.But problem is that on button click new popup opens and as soon as server side code gets executed second popup closes.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your question as much as you **it helps in understanding your problem**
Anyways I guess your problem is that the page gets post back... You need to open your second Modal Popup from Server Side..
Here is a nice example of it: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/215040/ModalPopupExtender-from-Server-Side-Code

Answer (score 0):

write this in your codebehid button click event

```
 popupid.Hide(); //hide the popup which you dont want to show.
                    //it will close when you click on submit button

    popupid1.show();
```

write this in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var ShowVerifyInventory = '<%=popup_verifyInventory.ClientID %>';
         function ShowPopUp_verifyInventory() {
             $find(ShowVerifyInventory).show();
         }

         var HideVerifyInventory = '<%=popup_verifyInventory.ClientID %>';
         function HidePopUp_verifyInventory() {
             $find(HideVerifyInventory).hide();
         }
</script>
```